Delete all prior files in dist folder before 'gulp build' task begins?
I'm wanting to deploy a website to a testing server. I have literally spent days watching Youtubes, Lynda.com/LinkedIn Learning, etc. to find the best way to 'gulp build' a dist folder for me to upload (this advice varies, too) to my testing server.
Question: Do I need to manually delete old files in the dist folder from previous testing builds?
I do haves js scripts as part of my theme.
This is in the exports file of  gulpfile.js
    // export tasks**
    exports.scss = scss
    exports.css = css
    exports.images = images;
    exports.fonts = fonts
    exports.html = html;
    exports.fileincludeTask = fileincludeTask
    exports.copyLibs = copyLibs
    exports.cleanTemp = cleanTemp
    exports.cleanDist = cleanDist

Will this handle my needs to clean and delete old dist files previously used and create an updated dist folder?
One more: I have git set up from inside VSCode. Do I need to upload the dist folder to git?
Kind regards, a newbie
I haven't tried yet. I am scared I might mess things up.

Okay, update. I went ahead and backed up the files in another folder, then deleted (right mac mouse to deleted in VSCode). I then quit VSCode, restarted and immediately typed 'gulp build' and it populated my dist folder which I was able to upload. My test site is functioning well. Thank goodness it worked.
